# ClojureScript - convert arbitrary JavaScript object to Clojure Script map

Tags: clojure, clojurescript

I am trying to convert a Javascript object to a Clojure. However, I get the following error :

```
 (js/console.log (js->clj e)) ;; has no effect
 (pprint (js->clj e)) ;; No protocol method IWriter.-write defined for type object: [object Geoposition]
```

Yes, this object comes from the Geolocation API. I suppose that I have to extend `IEncodeClojure` and `IWriter`, but I have no clue how.

For instance adding the following :

```
(extend-protocol IEncodeClojure
  Coordinates
  (-js->clj [x options]
    (println "HERE " x options)))
```

Yields an error when loading my code : `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'prototype' of undefined`

Comment: Are you sure you have an object there and not `undefined`? What does `(js/console.log (undefined? e))`  yield?

Comment: @TimPote It is not undefined : using Clojure timbre, I get the name of the object. Using js/console.log I get the same js object when doing `(js/console.log e)` and `(js/console.log (js->clj e))`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`js->clj` only works for `Object`, anything with custom constructor (see `type`) will be returned as is.

see: https://github.com/clojure/clojurescript/blob/master/src/main/cljs/cljs/core.cljs#L9319

I suggest doing this instead:

```
(defn jsx->clj
  [x]
  (into {} (for [k (.keys js/Object x)] [k (aget x k)])))
```

**UPDATE** for correct solution see Aaron's answer, gotta use `goog.object`

Comment: `aget` should not be used for obtaining values of JS objects: https://clojurescript.org/news/2017-07-14-checked-array-access

Answer (score 13):

The accepted answer wasn't working for me with the javascript object `window.performance.timing`. This is because `Object.keys()` doesn't actually return the props for the `PerformanceTiming` object.

```
(.keys js/Object (.-timing (.-performance js/window))
; => #js[]
```

This is despite the fact that the props of `PerformanceTiming` are indeed iterable with a vanilla JavaScript loop:

```
for (a in window.performance.timing) {
  console.log(a);
}
// navigationStart
// unloadEventStart
// unloadEventEnd
// ...
```

The following is what I came up with to convert an arbitrary JavaScript object to a ClojureScript map. Note the use of two simple Google Closure functions.

- `goog.typeOf` wraps `typeof`, which isn't normally accessible to us in ClojureScript. I use this to filter out props which are functions.
- `goog.object.getKeys` wraps `for (prop in obj) {...}`, building up an array result which we can reduce into a map.

## Solution (flat)

```clj
(defn obj->clj
  [obj]
  (-> (fn [result key]
        (let [v (goog.object/get obj key)]
          (if (= "function" (goog/typeOf v))
            result
            (assoc result key v))))
      (reduce {} (.getKeys goog/object obj))))
```

## Solution (recursive)

**Update:** This solution will work for nested maps.

```clj
(defn obj->clj
  [obj]
  (if (goog.isObject obj)
    (-> (fn [result key]
          (let [v (goog.object/get obj key)]
            (if (= "function" (goog/typeOf v))
              result
              (assoc result key (obj->clj v)))))
        (reduce {} (.getKeys goog/object obj)))
    obj))
```

Comment: `aget` should not be used for obtaining values of JS objects: https://clojurescript.org/news/2017-07-14-checked-array-access

Comment: @kamituel, thanks for pointing that out. I have updated my answer to use `goog.object/get`.

Comment: This is great! How would you keywordize the keys?

Comment: To keywordize, it seemed as easy as wrapping the whole `(if ...)` with `(clojure.walk/keywordize-keys (if ...))`

Comment: @RobertJBerger, an optimization on that would be to change `key` on line 8 to `(keyword key)`.

Comment: Any tips on how to get rid of "Cannot infer target type in expression (. goog/object getKeys obj)" warning?

Comment: @NikoNyrh if you do away with the isObject check and trust the caller, you can type hint obj in the function's signature like `[^js/Object obj]`

Answer (score 2):

Two approaches that do not require writing custom conversion functions - they both employ standard JavaScript functions to loose the custom prototype and thus enable `clj->js` to work correctly.

## Using JSON serialization

This approach just serializes to JSON and immediately parses it:

```
(js->clj (-> e js/JSON.stringify js/JSON.parse))
```

**Advantages:**

- does not require any helper function
- works for nested objects, with/without prototype
- supported in every browser

**Disadvantages:**

- performance might be a problem in critical pieces of codebase
- will strip any non-serializable values, like functions.

---

## Using Object.assign()

This approach is based on [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign) and it works by copying all the properties from `e` onto a fresh, plain (no custom prototype) `#js {}`.

```
(js->clj (js/Object.assign #js {} e))
```

**Advantages:**

- does not require any helper function

**Disadvantages:**

- works on flat objects, if there is another nested object withing `e`, it won't be converted by `clj->js`.
- `Object.assign()` [is not supported by old browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Browser_compatibility), most notably - IE.

Comment: Interesting. Any advantages compared to the other solutions?

Comment: @nha I actually ended up using a different approach (JSON serialization). Updated my answer to explain both approaches, and pros/cons of each.

Comment: `Object.assign()` isn't working for `window.performance.timing`.

Answer (score 0):

```
(defn obj->clj
  ([obj]
   (obj->clj obj :keywordize-keys false))
  ([obj & opts]
   (let [{:keys [keywordize-keys]} opts
         keyfn (if keywordize-keys keyword str)]
     (if (and (not-any? #(% obj) [inst? uuid?])
              (goog.isObject obj))
       (-> (fn [result k]
             (let [v (goog.object/get obj k)]
               (if (= "function" (goog/typeOf v))
                 result
                 (assoc result (keyfn k) (apply obj->clj v opts)))))
           (reduce {} (.getKeys goog/object obj)))
       obj))))
```

Small problem with the original above is that JS treats #inst and #uuid as objects. Seems like those are the only tagged literals in clojure

I also added the option to keywordize keys by looking at js->clj source