# Using React Native MapView in ClojureScript Reagent

Tags: react-native, clojure, android-mapview, clojurescript, reagent

I am trying to use `MapView` from https://github.com/airbnb/react-native-maps using Reagent. It works fine but how could I get local state for `MapView` when `onRegionChange` event is fired? Trying to use current/component but it is always `nil`.

```
(def Expo (js/require "expo"))
(def map-view (r/adapt-react-class (.-MapView Expo)))

(defn my-map []
   (r/create-class
     {:component-did-mount (fn [this] 
                       (println "component mount "))
      :reagent-render (fn []
                  (let [this (r/current-component)]
                    [map-view {:style {:flex 1}
                               :initialRegion {:latitude 37.78825
                                               :longitude -122.4324
                                               :latitudeDelta 0.0922
                                               :longitudeDelta 0.0421}
                                 :onRegionChange (fn []
                                                  ;; Would like to see state here.
                                                  (println (.. this -state))                                                       )}]))}))
```

Comment: Why are you requiring expo and calling `.-MapView` on it?

Comment: Here is expo documentation for more info https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/map-view.html

Comment: Ah thanks. I'll look at it this evening.

Answer (score 1):

#### Region information

The `onRegionChange` callback has `Region` as argument. `Region` has the following signature:

```
type Region {
  latitude: Number,
  longitude: Number,
  latitudeDelta: Number,
  longitudeDelta: Number,
}
```

You can get the values from the Region by using [`goog.object/get`](https://developer.pubref.org/static/apidoc/global/closure/goog/object/get.html).

If you get the `region` and extract the values from it your `my-map` looks like:

```
(defn my-map []
  [map-view {:style         {:flex 1}
             :initialRegion {:latitude       52.3702
                             :longitude      4.89516
                             :latitudeDelta  0.0922
                             :longitudeDelta 0.0421}
             :onRegionChange (fn [region]
                               (alert (str "Latitude: "
                                           (goog.object/get region "latitude")
                                           "\nLongitude: "
                                           (goog.object/get region "longitude"))))}])
```

You can obtain the `latitudeDelta` and `longitudeDelta` in the same manner.

When you drag the map the latitude and longitude show up:

[image: react-native-maps]

#### The component

If you want access to the component itself your code works fine, you just have to [visualize it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32467299/clojurescript-convert-arbitrary-javascript-object-to-clojure-script-map):

```
(defn jsx->clj
  [x]
  (into {} (for [k (.keys js/Object x)] [k (aget x k)])))

(defn my-map []
  (let [this (r/current-component)]
    [map-view {:style          {:flex 1}
               :initialRegion  {:latitude       37.78825
                                :longitude      -122.4324
                                :latitudeDelta  0.0922
                                :longitudeDelta 0.0421}
               :onRegionChange (fn [region]
                                 ;; Would like to see state here.

                                 (alert "The component..."
                                        (str (jsx->clj this))))}]))
```

This prints something like:

[image: Print component itself]

Not sure if you can do anything with the component, I think you need the `Region` information.

Comment: Thanks for your hard work. But my problem was to get local state not region. Because local state has child component, region, markers etc. I need all local state of that component. How do I get local state?

Comment: Thank you for the question. ;) Glad I am now on my way to programming a React Native app as well. And aha I see. When I look in `this` the "state" is `nil`, also when there are markers available. Maybe you can create your own override of a callback function that has more state in `:componentDidMount`. This is a begin: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43176862/how-can-i-get-current-location-latlong-in-react-native-maps/43188042#43188042.